# Monitoring postfix mail throughput

Tags: postfix, email-server, sendmail, performance-monitoring

I have a number of CentOS machines running postfix and sendmail. Is there some thing that I can use to monitor the current message throughput of a mail server from its logs?  I'd particularly would like to know the messages processed per second in real-time.  Unfortunately postfix does not include this sort of functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mailgraph.schweikert.ch/ should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Maybe glTail would do the trick?
http://fudgie.org/

Comment: glTail is definitely real-time, but I'm afraid it's way too flashy and graphically intensive for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check awstats: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#MAIL
and cacti / mrtg
http // forums.cacti.net/about1571-0-asc-0.html
or
http // netilium.org/~mad/technotes/postfixstat/