# Postfix mail server monitoring commands

Tags: postfix, centos5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring postfix mail throughput](https://serverfault.com/questions/69095/monitoring-postfix-mail-throughput)

I would like to monitor postfix mail server. I currently setup this mail server on centos 5.5.
Is there anyway to monitor about postfix mail server.(for example message size, the number of user using SNMT port, etc.)I goggling about this but not satisfied. Is there any reference about postfix mail server monitoring commands?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember many postfix monitoring command all i know is about postfix tools mailq, postqueue, but i there is a useful tool named [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/),  that can help you on that and print many beautiful graph.